# Disable Rubocop argument list length

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Currently I'm getting feedback from Rubocop saying "Avoid parameter lists longer than 5 parameters."

What is the #Rubocop:disable command to disable this? I'm happy with the code having an extra argument so I don't want to change it.

Comment: Question is not clear. Is there a certain command that you are asking what is does, or are you asking how to disable the feature?

Comment: I'm asking how to disable the feature

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could drop a file named `.rubocop.yml` in your project root directory with the following content.

```
Metrics/ParameterLists:
  Enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks :) I used this a did 
`# rubocop:disable Metrics/ParameterLists`

Comment: Might make sense to point that orien's answer disable the check globally in the whole project. Whereas IAmAkittycatAMA's magic comment disables the check only locally [for a line or a block](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#disabling-cops-within-source-code). Btw nice to see you, @orien...

Answer (score 4):

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/ParameterLists
```

your function goes here

```
# rubocop:enable Metrics/ParameterLists
```

Answer (score 3):

For your convenience, here is my .rubocop.yml I frequently used.

See formal explanation of .rubocop.yml [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml).

```
AllCops:
  Excludes:
    - Berksfile
    - recipes/basic.rb
    - attributes/*.rb

# Customize rules
Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 95

MethodLength:
  Max: 35

Metrics/AbcSize:
   Enabled: false

BlockLength:
  Max: 70
```

I constantly bump by rubocop errors and warning. Thus I've published this post.

[Common Rubocop Errors: Improve Your Ruby Code Quality](http://www.dennyzhang.com/rubocop_errors/)